# Just slightly confused, as i do not know what the 'bottom' bits of a Hex int in java means

Tags: java, bit

For a certain programming project, I need to perform operations on the "bottom two bits" of an `int` in java set to `0x0000`, however I am not sure which end of the `int` is "bottom" and which is "top".

Comment: I would think the last ones, for instance in `0x00000011` the bottom bits would be `11`

Comment: depends what 'bottom' and 'top' mean ;-) is the 'bottom' bit the least significant one?

Comment: @OscarRyz that would be bottom 5 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology is usually "high order bits" are the most significant (the first ones) and "low order bits" are the least significant (the last ones). Bit positions are referred to by their zero-based position counting from the right, which corresponds with the numerical value of the bit being `2` <sup>`position`</sup>

Assuming that "bottom" is synonymous with "low", that would make the "bottom two bits" the *last* two bits, or bits in position `1` and `0`.

In java, you can get the those bits using a [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29):

```
int i; // some integer
int bottomTwoBits = i & 3; // 3 is "11" in binary
```